# Second argument to the print() function causing performance hit

Tags: python

Okay.
I'm using Python 3.3.2 and IDLE. 
I was just playing around in the interactive shell displaying the character representations of numbers and noticed that when I remove the newline character it impacts performance massively.
This is the way I am doing it.

```
for x in range(2056):print(chr(x),end='')
```

Without the second argument to the print() function it runs smoothly and takes a few seconds to complete but when adding end='' it is as though someone is typing the characters very slowly and takes a good minute to complete.
Was wondering if this is something to do with my set-up or whether anyone else has noticed this, also whether it is specific to IDLE, or any information on this at all would be appreciated.

Comment: IDLE has generally poor performance, it can't be relied up for real performance tests.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with IDLE's needing to wrap the text to the window size, which is much easier when your print statements contain line breaks. The bigger the chunk of linebreak-free text, the longer it takes to wrap. Since IDLE keeps a history of your entire session, it can accumulate quite a lot of text in its window, which may need to be wrapped on a regular basis.

IDLE does seem particularly slow at it compared to other programs.

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience IDLE is fairly slow especially with line breaks. There's a slight but unoticable difference in the console:

```
$ time python -c 'for x in range(2056):print(chr(x),end="")' > /dev/null
python -c 'for x in range(2056):print(chr(x),end="")' > /dev/null  0.02s user 0.02s system 98% cpu 0.041 total
$ time python -c 'for x in range(2056):print(chr(x))' > /dev/null 
python -c 'for x in range(2056):print(chr(x))' > /dev/null  0.03s user 0.01s system 92% cpu 0.036 total
```

Give IPython a try instead. It's nearly instant for both commands, and is a much better repl than IDLE.